# Tracking phone number in Google analytics not working

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, event-tracking

So i'm new to event tracking, and i have followed the guide s online for phone and mail tracking (at least i think i do) but it seems like i don't get any data in GA. I used this guide: https://www.northstudio.com/blog/how-set-event-tracking-google-analytics

I'm using WP and DIVI theme tracking phone numbers and emails on this site: http://byg-ide.dk

In GA event tracking, this is what i have inserted:

**Mail tracking:**

Category: mail

Event: klik

label: send mail

**Phone tracking**

Category: telefonnr

Event: klik

label: opringning

Can anyone tell me why this is not tracking properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues I noticed:

1. You are mixing `_gaq` and `ga` calls. The former is for classic GA, and the latter is for UA. I don't see the ga.js library on your site, so I assume you use UA, in which case your `_gaq` calls should be translated into `ga` calls, like this:

   ```
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','telefonnr','klik','opringning']);
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   ga('send', 'event', 'telefonnr', 'klik', 'opringning');
   ```
2. Second thing is that your code is using smart quotes rather than straight quotes (if I only got a dollar for every time I saw this mistake):

   ```
   ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘telefonnr’, ‘klik’, ‘opringning’);
   ```

   should have straight quotes

   ```
   ga('send', 'event', 'telefonnr', 'klik', 'opringning');
   ```

Comment: Thanks i will check that out later today - i was just going blind looking on it.